# Java Domain Exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I had written a restful web service. The contract of the restful web service is to receive parameters, communicate to a external service via SSL and respond back to the client. There are no issues in the service contract and the service. The service design was good and all the checked exceptions have been caught in the catch block but after a few service testing, then it seemed that the unchecked exceptions are not handled properly. Is there are any way to encapsulate these unchecked exception using domain exceptions. To be simple, how to handle or anticipate the unchecked exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You should always have a single place in your code where you handle all exceptions and what you describe sounds like you have a mess of handling code all around, wherever a method is called that declares checked exceptions. Use this code in lower-level code that encounters checked exceptions:

```
try { 
  ...
catch (RuntimeException e) { throw e;} 
catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
```

And at the exception barrier (that central place mentioned) use

```
try {
  ...
catch (Throwable t) { // logging, returning error response, whatever
}
finally { // global resource cleanup
}
```

Doing more than this is required only in special cases, which you will find are not very common in the code base, and that is when your lower-level methods acquire resources additional to the resources already acquired for each request. An example could be file I/O. In such cases it is of course mandatory to use a `try-finally` to take care of that extra resource, but you still must not `catch` and swallow exceptions: the main exception barrier still needs to know there was a problem and do its cleanup.

Comment: eh looks a lot like pokemon exception handling, :(

Comment: @Woot4Moo I think you're mixing up concepts. It would be that only if it were spread around code. One central catch-all place is good practice, and used in projects around the world. Most frameworks support it natively.

Comment: Catching Exception is not a good practice.  You cannot possibly believe you are able to recover from every exception do you?

Comment: Of course I can. If I serve a web request and an exception is thrown, I will by all means want to: 1. log it; 2. rollback all transactions; 3. clean up ThreadLocals and all other such state; 4. generate a 500 Internal Server Error. But I really wonder what makes you doubt this approach---how is your professional experience any different?

Comment: I have seen people catch Exception from a File IO error and just continue, irrespective of logging, that is not handling the exception properly.  The problem occurs in cases such as this when people catch the 2nd level Exception (the only thing worse is Throwable) and have no clue as to all the possible states their code could be in.  Further doing a clean up inside an Exception block only has a good chance of succeeding if it is a try/finally with the Exception block (which is almost always ghastly).  Try/finally around the general method does not guarantee the exceptional state was handled.

Comment: Sure, cleanup is split between `catch` and `finally` (logging and error response goes into `catch`). As for file IO and other resources acquired locally, local try-finally block is mandatory. But these are all just extensions to my point and a great deal of real-world exceptions is dealt with in exactly the same way---the way I describe it.

Comment: My idea is that is there  is any way to encapsulate unchecked exceptions by means of domain exceptions so that it can be transferred to further layers, For eg

pulbic class MYDomainException
{
public MYDomainException(Exception E)
{
}
}

Comment: VVEKSELVA, what specifically do you have in mind with those domain exceptions? What kind of special handling do you envisage for them?

Comment: Marko Topolnik, Let me put ideas in this way,

We call a third party api like this,

Foo f = ThirdPartyLib.getFoo();
f.doSomething();

and only in certain test cases we feel that f would null and a null pointer exception would be thrown. So we change our code to ,

Foo f = ThirdPartyLib.getFoo();
if(f!=null)
{
f.doSomething();
}
contd.,

Comment: Compiler didn't notify the developers since its unchecked exception. This is an example of such a situation,where  we might be unaware of the unchecked exceptions in the third party apis and those might not be handled for sure, since we are unaware of it.
So if we encapsulate all the unchecked exceptions in a domain specific way like the below , then exceptions would be handled like the below,
try
{
Foo f= ThirdPartyLib.getFoo();
}
catch(DomainException e)
{ 
ExceptionHanlded
}

Comment: But the 3rd party lib doesn't throw `DomainException`? I don't get the point of this. And what handling did you have in mind for an NPE?

Comment: I Agree the third party lib won't throw domain exceptions.I will put my query in other way,Client calls my serviceA which in turn calls someotherService
public class SeviceA
{ 
 public String response(String argument)
 {
  //Here I'm calling some other service,
    String someOtherServiceResponse = SomeOtherService();
  
  someOtherServiceResponse.getData();
  .......
 }
}
In case if the SomeOtherService returns null then nullpointerexception is thrown to the client, which I don't want to do.I just want to tell the client that error at our end we'll inform by just handling all the exceptions.

Comment: If you had an exception barrier, you'd never propagate any exceptions to the client. As for your new scenario: if the NPE happened in a 3rd party lib, then you **would** propagate it to the client, and would like to do it differently only if the NPE is thrown by your code? Why? You should **never** do that.

Comment: Thanks Marko I got it, can you please explain exception barrier still further not just NPE with an citation.

Answer (score 0):

In the specific case of a restful web service, the framework has a 'catch-all' handler that does something you don't like. So, contra some other answers here, there's nothing evil about adding more or different handling. The framework's handler is certainly not cleaning up for you, so you can only make things better by cleaning up for yourself. Thus, you have two choices.

1. you can add an exception mapper to your list of providers, as per the JAX-RS standard.
2. You can wrap your code in a try/catch of Throwable, and then construct a Response that appeals to you in the catch handler.

Without knowing what toolkit you are using for JAX-RS I can't be more detailed about (1).

Comment: I advise an exception barrier, you advise an exception barrier. Please explain how is your advice "contra" mine.

Comment: Okay its fine for the Restful frameworks, but in case of service layers how to hadle the situation, since the service may call some other service which may throw exception which we mayn't know (that might be unchecked). Is there are any way to encapsulate or catch those exceptions

Answer (score -1):

RuntimeExceptions should indicate **coding errors**, so ideally you should fix the bugs rather than trying to handle them. Unfortunately some library developers misuse RTEs for non-bugs and force you to catch them. You can wrap a RuntimeException in an Exception.

```
....
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    throw new MyCheckedException("Failed to...", e);
}
```

EDIT: It seems it's a controversial view these days. I know that bad checked exceptions can be a pain. But good use of checked exceptions helps clients and implementers to understand the contract. Using RuntimeExceptions for non-bugs may make it easier to work with an API in the 'happy case', when you don't care about exceptions, but much harder to know what to expect of the 'sad case' when you do. It also makes it harder for implementers of interfaces to know what's expected of them - which RuntimeExceptions they are or aren't allowed to throw etc.

Comment: Quite the opposite is the case: developers **welcome** newer libraries that don't declare checked exceptions, which have proven themselves as major PITAs all the way. What is and isn't a **coding error** cannot be decided up-front by the library designer.

Comment: **Some** developers welcome libraries like that. I, for one, hate that approach to exceptions. I understand that exception-handling can be verbose, but I don't agree that abandoning checked-exceptions and ignoring the semantics of runtime exceptions is the right approach. If you look at the JDK you'll see that RuntimeExceptions are used to indicate bugs (e.g. caller has passed in an invalid parameter or called a method when they shouldn't). Of course not every coding problem can be caught, but those that can be caught are indicated with RuntimeExceptions rather than Exceptions.

Comment: Name **any** checked exception in JDK and I'll name a scenario where it can **only be raised by a coding error**. BTW you really enjoy the mess made by the reflection API? At **least** all those exceptions should be a part of some `ReflectionException` hierarchy. As for JDK, the checked exceptions are there today only for historical reasons. If they could get rid of them, **they would**. BTW I am not the downvoter.

Comment: Right, but the point I'm making isn't that checked exceptions can't indicate bugs. It's that runtime exceptions should.

Comment: But that point is backwards---the prime requirement is not to enforce exception handling on coding-error situations. And anyway, the reverse is *ipso facto* also true---some unchecked exceptions are **not** the result of coding errors, but true exceptional and recoverable situations. A library designer cannot possibly know the character of error from a higher-lever perspective.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. The good thing about runtime exceptions, with their original semantics, is that you _never_ have to catch them and you'll never get them if your code is free from bugs. A library designer can validate method parameters, current state etc. They can't check everything of course, but I'm not claiming that.

Comment: `try { return a.getB().getC().getD(); } catch (NullPointerException e) { return null; }`---was this a bug? You may call it bad practice, but it sure isn't a bug.

Comment: OK, well we disagree on what a bug is. My view is that if you're calling a method on a null reference then that's definitely a bug.

Comment: A **bug** is something the customer complains about, it's an observed misbehavior. The accepted terminology for your "bug" is *bad practice*. Also, are you familiar with the concept "Garbage In, Garbage Out"? Under your definition any GIGO code is one giant bug, but there is a world out there that disagrees.

Comment: A customer doesn't need to complain for you to have a bug. Your definition doesn't match [that on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug). What is bad practice is to catch NullPointerException because that's addressing the symptom rather than the cause. It is easy to alter the code to avoid NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: "Customer complaining" was just a charming way of describing it. Other than that, the definitions match perfectly. Maybe you are missing the point of my code: it's just shorthand for checking for `null` at every boring step and returning `null`. There are no causes and no symptoms---just a slightly misguided idiom, since the NPE may happen for other reasons as well, and even **cause a bug** in some scenarios---that's why it's bad practice. But no misbehavior, no bug.

Comment: The point is about **contracts**. If you pass in messy input and I'm expecting messy input then that's fine. If you pass in messy input and my contract says "no messy input" then that's not OK. That's when a RuntimeException should be used.

Comment: But what if my API calls other API internally? The input that causes that internal call to fail with an unchecked exception is invalid input. Does my API implementation contain a bug, or is the bug with the caller of my API? I can even specify in detail that such-and-such input will result in such-and-such unchecked exception. Where is the bug then?

Comment: NullPointerException is slightly different because it's built-in functionality that you can rely on. However, runtime exceptions in library code are not reliable because they are not declared as part of the interface, someone could easily implement a version that does not throw the exceptions you are expecting.

Comment: Many unchecked exceptions are indeed declared in the Javadoc. They don't have to be declared in code to be part of contract.

Comment: If the input your API receives is invalid, then you want to flag that up. Your code could validate it or you could rely on the internal API to validate it. Either way, a RTE is raised. The bug is with the calling code.

Comment: Exactly, but Javadoc does not enforce anything. And do you want to rely on an implementer of your interface having read the Javadoc? Also, as RuntimeExceptions are propagated it is easy for them not to appear in the Javadoc, or appear only in some implementations.

Comment: RE: "The bug is with the calling code"---so we agree that intentionally writing calls that may violate the contract is perfectly fine. My library doesn't have to validate its parameters up front---I'll delegate that to the called API.

Comment: RE "Javadoc does not enforce anything"---of course I can rely on the implementer to respect the contract! If he doesn't---the bug is not mine. Do you believe in writing code that fights against other people's bugs, right down to the last one? That turns buggy code into bugless code? That's impossible, not even in theory.

Comment: Right, you don't really want to duplicate validation all over the place. If your code is given correct inputs it will work correctly. If it isn't given correct inputs it (or something it calls) raises an RTE. To the caller, it's all the same.

Comment: I believe in catching bugs early and preventing bugs whenever possible. It is impossible to ignore checked exceptions. It is easy to inadvertently or otherwise ignore runtime exceptions. It doesn't matter who's fault the bug is, if there's a bug in the code, I want to know about it as early as possible. We can't catch all bugs, but that doesn't mean we can't catch a lot.

Comment: And so, by all means, you will. The first time you run the code, you'll get a detailed stacktrace of your unchecked exception. That's the beauty of the system---handle all errors at one central place.

Comment: Checked exceptions help find bugs at compile time rather than run time. Sure, novice coders can do crazy things like swallowing checked exceptions but you have to manage that in a different way.

Comment: I'm an experienced dev, and **I hate checked exceptions**. They don't indicate bugs to me, they just make me write boilerplate code. If I use some reflection for a known set of classes, what recoverable errors am I supposed to handle? I get up to 10 different checked exceptions, tell me please how they help me write safer code?

Comment: `try { /* reflection */ } catch (Exception e) { System.err.println("Check your code, dummy, you've got a bug!"); e.printStackTrace(); }` Tell me how to improve my exception handling code to produce code that will perform better and safer.

Comment: Yeah, the exceptions in the reflection API are a good example of how not to write checked exceptions. They reveal too much implementation detail to clients that aren't interested. There is no abstract exception class, so you have to handle each exception separately. I guess the way to handle is to write helpers and wrappers.

Comment: The true way would be for those exceptions to be *unchecked exceptions*. I would have zero problems with them in that case.

Comment: Even better would be to have a single abstract exception with multiple concrete exceptions that you could catch individually if you wanted or not, if you didn't. That way you wouldn't have to catch Exception which is rarely a good idea, but would retain the RTE=bug semantics.  I know bad checked exceptions are a pain. But they are valuable to catch bugs at compile time, if done right.